# SharePoint 2010 Audiences - unable to edit audience

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, audiences

I have created and compiled audiences in SP 2010, but am unable to go back in and edit any of the members or rules?

I have restarted IIS, checked all user profile services are running and i have full admin / farm admin rights but still no edit command available?

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[To edit an audience](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262169%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section2)
1. Verify that you have at least one of the following administrative credentials:

```
  You are a member of the Farm Administrators group.   
  You are a service application administrator for the User Profile service application that contains the audience that you want to edit.   
  You are an administrator for the Audience feature of the User Profile service application that contains the audience that you want to edit.
```

1. On the Central Administration Web site, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
2. On the Service Applications page, in the list of service applications, click the row of the User Profile service application that you want to configure.
   Clicking the row activates options in the ribbon.
3. In the Operations group of the ribbon, click Manage.
4. On the Manage Profile Service page, in the People section, click Manage Audiences.
5. On the View Audiences page, in the list of audiences, point to the name of the audience that you want to edit, click the arrow that appears, and then click Edit.
6. On the Edit Audience page, you can make the following changes:

   In the Properties section, you can change the name or description of the audience.
   In the Owner box, you can type the account name of the user that will own and manage this audience.
   You can click Check Names to verify that you have typed the name correctly, or you can click Browse to search for an account name.
    You can select Satisfy all of the rules or Satisfy any of the rules to determine the    membership of this audience.
7. Click OK to apply your changes.